# Is there an easy way to quote a type with constrained parameters?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, type-variables

```
> {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
> import Language.Haskell.TH
> import Control.Monad
```

Let's say I have a class like [`Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-class-0.1.2.0/docs/Data-Default-Class.html#t:Default)

```
> class Default a where
>  def :: a
```

There's a straightforward way to define instances for types that also have a `Monoid` instance, like

```
instance Monoid a => Default a where
  def = mempty
```

but because of the overlapping problem and to make this more controllable one might provide a TH macro instead.

<sup>(Yes, I know we could use `-XDerivingVia`, I'm not interested in such a solution here.)</sup>

```
> makeMonoidDefault :: Q Type -> DecsQ
> makeMonoidDefault instT = sequence
>   [ InstanceD Nothing [] <$> [t| Default $instT |] <*> [d|
>         $(varP $ mkName "def") = mempty |] ]
```

This can than be invoked easily with a quoted type, like

```
makeMonoidDefault [t| Maybe () |]
```

to allow

```
*Main> def :: Maybe ()
Nothing
```

But this does not allow something like the parameterised instance

```
instance Semigroup a => Default (Maybe a) where
  def = mempty
```

That could be done with another macro:

```
> makeMonoidDefault' :: Q (Cxt,Type) -> DecsQ
> makeMonoidDefault' cxtInstT = do
>  (cxt, instT) <- cxtInstT
>  sequence
>   [ InstanceD Nothing cxt <*> [t| Default $(pure instT) |] <*> [d|
>         $(varP $ mkName "def") = mempty |] ]
```

But this is now much more awkward to actually use:

```
makeMonoidDefault' $ do
   tParam <- pure . VarT <$> newName "a"
   sgcxt <- [t| Semigroup $tParam |]
   maybet <- [t| Maybe $tParam |]
   return ([sgcxt], maybet)
```

or

```
makeMonoidDefault' $ do
   tParam <- pure . VarT <$> newName "a"
   ((,) . (:[])) <$> [t| Semigroup $tParam |]
                 <*> [t| Maybe $tParam |]
```

- Is there a way to write this without explicitly using `VarT` and applicative combinators, preferrably in a single quotation?
- Should the argument of `makeMonoidDefault'` be something other than `Q (Cxt, Type)`?

Comment: BTW, another thing I find dubious is `$(varP $ mkName "def")` for the method declaration in the macro. Just writing `def = mempty` there does not work.

Comment: Why not `makeMonoidDefault' :: Q Type -> Q Type -> DecsQ`? You can then pattern-match on the type to make it a `Cxt`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia both context and type need to be in the same monadic context, invoking the same `newName "a"`. And I don't really understand what you want to pattern-match.

Comment: I meant if the context needed to be more than one element long, then you could pattern-match a tuple to unpack it. Though maybe that's unnecessary because maybe the tuple is already fine as a constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky solution I came up with is this:

```hs
-- Quote.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Quote where

import Language.Haskell.TH

class Default a where
  def :: a

makeMonoidDefault' :: Q Type -> DecsQ
makeMonoidDefault' q = do
  t <- q
  case t of
    ForallT _ cxt instT -> sequence
      [ InstanceD Nothing cxt <$> [t| Default $(pure instT) |] <*> [d|
            $(varP 'def) = mempty |] ]
    _ -> fail "<some nice error message>"
```

Then you can use it like this:

```hs
-- Main.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, ExplicitForAll #-}
import Quote

makeMonoidDefault' [t|forall a. Semigroup a => Maybe a|]

main = pure ()
```

Comment: I like how this looks a lot! But is there anything that could go badly wrong with this approach?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I just changed `mkName "def"` to `'def` that should avoid accidentally capturing the wrong `def`. I can't think of anything else obvious that could go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of @Noughtmare's solution, you can do more in the quotation bracket:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

makeMonoidDefault :: Q Type -> DecsQ
makeMonoidDefault q = do
  t <- q
  let (ctx, instT) = case t of
        ForallT _ ctx instT -> (ctx, instT)
        _ -> ([], t)
  [d|
    instance $(pure $ foldCtx ctx) => Default $(pure instT) where
      def = mempty
    |]
  where
    foldCtx l = foldl AppT (TupleT $ length l) l
```

It can be used in any of these ways:

```hs
makeMonoidDefault [t|forall a. Semigroup a => Maybe a|]
makeMonoidDefault [t|forall a b. (Monoid a, Monoid b) => (a,b)|]
makeMonoidDefault [t|Maybe ()|]
```

and it no longer has the weird bit about `def`.  (By the way, the `ConstraintKinds` pragma is required for the case where this is no context, and the generated context is `()`.)

Comment: Neat! Still, folding the `Cxt` list just to generate a tuple à la ConstraintKinds in the instance quotation is a bit convoluted. – All these use cases would also work with `InstanceD Nothing cxt ...`, right?

Comment: Yes!  The instances generated here should be the same as those generated by @Noughtmare's.  The only way I could figure out to make `def` work without wrapping it with `varP` is to put the whole `instance` in the same quotation block.  But, to do that, I needed to insert the context in its own splice, which required the constraint tuple.  I suppose it's just moving the "convolutedness" from one spot to another.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change up the design a bit. For instance:

```
makeMonoidDefault [d| instance Semigroup a => Default (Maybe a) |]
```

This is a bit redundant in that it mentions `Default` twice. (And you really should check that it actually does declare the class you expect it to.) But on the plus side, it gives you a lot of the structure you need as part of the argument.